# events.Sync not passing updated parameters in Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Grid whose value I want to refresh on radio button change. On radio button change, I am assigning the value to Hidden fields. For some reason, when the API call happens, the passed parameters still hold old value instead of loading new value of hidden field. I checked in HTML and the hidden fields do hold latest value.

The grid code is as below:

```
             .WebApi()
             .Events(events =>
             {
                 events.Sync("onSync");
             })
             .Read(read => read.Url("/api/LoadSettings/" + Model.HiddenFor1Value + "/" + Model.HiddenFor2Value))
             )
```

The Javascript code as below:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[type=radio][name=RadioSelected]").change(function () {
            radioChanged();
        });
    });
function radioChanged() {
        onSync();
    }
 function onSync() {
        console.log('reload start');
        var selectedColumnValue = $("input[name='RadioSelected']:checked").val();
        console.log(selectedColumnValue);
        $('#myHiddenFor1Value ').val(selectedColumnValue);
        $("#grd").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
        console.log('reload end');
    }
```

As I said, the hidden fields show latest value in html and the API call is working fine but the values passed are still old. Any idea is Sync doesn't refresh or pick latest values ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the read URL formed on page load doesn't change when we use the sync event. Or if it does, it wasn't working for me.

I just changed my onSync method to explicitly update the `transport.options.read.url` and it works as expected now :

```
 function onSync() {
        var Value1 = "123";
        var Value2 = "345";
        var grid = $('#grd').data('kendoGrid');
        grid.dataSource.transport.options.read.url = "/api/LoadSettings/" + Value1+ "/" + Value2;
    }
```